# How does the REPEAT FUNCTION deal with the trailing blanks from the string?

Tags: sas

I don't understand why the second and the third observation in C2 only have one blank between the copied string and the repeated string (Shown as 'XXX XXX' and 'Y Y') while there are 5 trailing blanks in 'XXX' and 7 trailing blanks in 'Y'? Does it conflict the results in LC2?

```
DATA EXAMPLE1;    
     INPUT GROUP @10 STRING $3.;    
     LEFT = 'X    ';    
     RIGHT = '    X';    
     C1 = SUBSTR(GROUP,1,2) ;     
     C2 = REPEAT(GROUP,1);       
     LGROUP = LENGTH(GROUP) ;    
     LSTRING = LENGTH(STRING) ;    
     LLEFT = LENGTH(LEFT);    
     LRIGHT = LENGTH(RIGHT);    
     LC1 = LENGTH(C1);    
     LC2 = LENGTH(C2); 
     DATALINES; 
     ABCDEFGH 123 
     XXX  4 
     Y 5 ;
```

Here is the output:
[PROC PRINT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvWBU.png)

Comment: from the book <Applied Statistics and the SAS Programming Language fifth edition>...

Comment: Did you chop off the beginning of the data step?  You do not have a DATA statement.  You cannot read values like XXX into a numeric variable named GROUP.  Why would you pass a numeric variable to the REPEAT() function?

Comment: oh, my bad, I forgot to start from a new line after using the ``` to start the coding area.

Answer (score 0):

You posted a PHOTOGRPAH of ODS output. You cannot tell anything about spaces from either of those. Turn on the plain old LISTING output and look at that.

So assuming you ran something like this:

```
data example;
  LENGTH GROUP $8;
  INPUT GROUP @10 STRING $3.;
  LEFT = 'X    ';
  RIGHT = '    X';
  C1 = SUBSTR(GROUP,1,2) ;
  C2 = REPEAT(GROUP,1);
  LGROUP = LENGTH(GROUP) ;
  LSTRING = LENGTH(STRING) ;
  LLEFT = LENGTH(LEFT);
  LRIGHT = LENGTH(RIGHT);
  LC1 = LENGTH(C1);
  LC2 = LENGTH(C2);
DATALINES;
ABCDEFGH 123
XXX  4
Y 5
;
```

The output should look like this:

```
Obs    GROUP       STRING    LEFT    RIGHT    C1    C2                  LGROUP    LSTRING    LLEFT    LRIGHT    LC1    LC2

 1     ABCDEFGH     123       X        X      AB    ABCDEFGHABCDEFGH       8         3         1         5       2      16
 2     XXX                    X        X      XX    XXX     XXX            3         1         1         5       2      11
 3     Y                      X        X      Y     Y       Y              1         1         1         5       1       9
```

But ODS mangles the outputs to make it look "pretty".

What do you see in the SAS log if you add

```
put group $quote.;
```

Comment: You mean like `put C2 $quote. ;` ? I did see the exact number of spaces by either using that or `put _ALL_;`  Can you explain how the $quote. worrks? Thank you!

Comment: `4QUOTE` is a format.  It works just like any other format, it displays the values passed to it.  The $QUOTE format quotes the value.  So you can see in the SAS log where the value starts and end.  The SAS LOG will not be displayed using proportional fonts so you can actually count the spaces.  YOu could also try the $HEX format.  A space character is 20 in hexadecimal.